# How to get specified project and specified version from JIRA REST API

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I take a look on this documentation http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest.
And I also tried some query by myself but I don't find the answer yet.

I would like to get the data from a specified project and version.
For example, I want to get data from project "ABC" and from that project contains versions, a1, a2, a3, a4.
But I want to get the data only version a1.

I tried the queries as below:

```
/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GRIFR14&fixVersion=15018
/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GRIFR14&version=15018
/rest/api/2/project/GRIFR14/version/15018
```

So i'm not sure how can I do to get the right info. Anyone can help?

Comment: I found the way to do that... /rest/api/2/search?jql=project=GRIFR14+and+fixVersion=15018

Answer (score 1):

The thing to do is to run the query in JIRA and then copy the URL from the link icon on that page to get the correct encoding